# Cannot import name BeatifulSoup4 from bs4

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm importing `bs4` like this, but it doesn't recognize it, it gives an error

Why I am getting this error?

[image]

```
cannot import name 'BeatifulSoup4' from 'bs4' 
(/Users/feyzaerdogan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py)
```

I am getting error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please don't post screenshots of text/data/code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the {} button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), it looks like the import needs to look like this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: Yazdım ama hala aynı hatayı alıyorum

Comment: I don't speak turkish (I guess it is turkish?). I have no idea what you are saying.